# Angular, get status code value from post request

Tags: angular, angular7, http-status-code-401

I want to get the StatusCode value from the post request in order to use it in my component.
This is what I have done:
Api call:

```
  Login(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(apiUrl + 'account/Login', user).subscribe();
  }
```

Method in component:

```
  Login() {
    this.user.UserName = this.loginForm.controls.userName.value;
    this.user.Password = this.loginForm.controls.password.value;

    this.api.Login(this.user)
  }
```

Now it is displayed only as error
[image]
The result should be like:
[image]

**Update**
It's not the cors issue...
Success login:
[image]

Comment: what is your back-end server?

Comment: @KhaledSameer asp.net core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an error callback in your subscribe to catch the errors from the HTTP Observable.

```
Login(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(apiUrl + 'account/Login', user).subscribe(
        (data) => {

        },
        (error) => {
           console.log(error);
           // get the status as error.status
        })
}
```

In case you want to get all the status code, irrespective of success or failure, you have to observe for `response` in your request.

Make your API call like:

```
this.http.post(apiUrl + 'account/Login', user, {observe: 'response'})
```

Log the response to see how you can access the status.

Comment: This works but how can I display the success login status code? For example: for success login server returns status code 200.

Comment: @Storm See the updated code if you want status irrespective of success or failure.